# replace some character values using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that has a column like below, I would like to use `tidyr::separate` to split it into 3 column. the issue is the first segment in some rows consist of two part (ex Troms-Romsa)

```
dummy data:
               df <- data.frame(
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 fka = c(
                   "Troms-Romsa - Female - 65+",
                   "Aust-Agder - Female - 20-29",
                   "Aust-Agder - Man - 50-64",
                   "Troms-Romsa - Man - 65+",
                   "Bergen - Man - 65+",
                   "Bergen - Female - 65+",
                   "Aust-Agder - Female - 30-39"))
```

Here the head:

```
                          fka
1  Troms-Romsa - Female - 65+
2 Aust-Agder - Female - 20-29
3    Aust-Agder - Man - 50-64
4     Troms-Romsa - Man - 65+
5          Bergen - Man - 65+
6       Bergen - Female - 65+
7 Aust-Agder - Female - 30-39
```

I tried to replace/rename those with `dplyr::across` like below but I couldn't make it.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., . ==  "Aust-Agder" , "AustAgder")))
```

How can fix this? My aim is to convert fka col into 3 cols like this at the end:

```
... %>%
separate(fka, c('county_name' , 'gender' , 'age_group'), sep="-" , extra = "merge")
```

Comment: It seems that your separator is a space plus a dash and another space, if you use a `" - "` as the separator instead of `"-"` that solves your problem.

Comment: @Koray two countys have "   -   "  ( space plus a dash and another space) in the original name too, because of that I tried to rename. like this in ´´´Finnmark   -   Finnmárku   -   Female   -   50-64```

Comment: Then one solution could be to use a separator with a simple regex trick like`" - Man - | - Female - "` then this will give you your first and third columns, whatever they contain. For the second column i would just do `mutate(sex=if_else(str_detect(fka,"Man"),"Man","Female")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the element of the rows in the data.frame so that the problematic element is the last in the row as in the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  fka = c(
    "Troms-Romsa - Female - 65+",
    "Aust-Agder - Female - 20-29",
    "Aust-Agder - Man - 50-64",
    "Troms-Romsa - Man - 65+",
    "Bergen - Man - 65+",
    "Bergen - Female - 65+",
    "Aust-Agder - Female - 30-39",
    "Finnmark - Finnmárku - Female - 50-64")) 

df$fka = (sapply(strsplit(x = df$fka, split = " - "), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = "_")))
df %>% separate(fka, c('age_group', 'gender',  'county_name'), sep="_" , extra = "merge")
```